# How to add a single annotation / marker with Mapbox Maps SDK for Android in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox-android

So, I have problem converting `kotlin` to `java` lang from their guideline. I have tried it on many way such as converting kotlin to java file but still cannot got it.

I have this code which is work with no annotation / marker. I call this method in `onCreateView`

```java
private void setMap() {
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do something like this in your fragment

```
 /**
  * Create circle on the place of the point parameter on Earth
  *
  * @param mapView Mapbox's mapView
  * @param point on Earth   -> can be created like this "Point point = Point.fromLngLat(50.0, 50.0);"
  */
 public void createCircleAnnotation(MapView mapView, Point point) {
     
     AnnotationPlugin annotationApi = AnnotationPluginImplKt.getAnnotations(mapView);
     CircleAnnotationManager circleAnnotationManager = CircleAnnotationManagerKt.createCircleAnnotationManager(annotationApi, new AnnotationConfig());

     // circle annotations options
     CircleAnnotationOptions circleAnnotationOptions = new CircleAnnotationOptions()
             .withPoint(point)
             .withCircleRadius(8.0)
             .withCircleColor("#ee4e8b")
             .withCircleBlur(0.5)
             .withCircleStrokeWidth(2.0)
             .withCircleStrokeColor("#ffffff");

     circleAnnotationManager.create(circleAnnotationOptions);
 }
```

The method is placing single circle annotation on to certain point on  the Earth defined by the point variable. The only two things, you need to do, is to provide mapbox's MapView into the parameter and the Point variable.

The truth is that docs are a bit inaccurate even for Kotlin (mainly because of the multiple versions especially v10 vs previous versions), but with the help of decompiling of Kotlin bytecode, it is kind of possible to find a solution to almost everything for Java

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Very pathetic documentation by @mapbox